# Ubuntu/Xubuntu 22.04 installation issue with RAID and full disk encryption

Tags: xubuntu, encryption, raid, lvm

I'm trying to install a ubuntu or xubuntu 22.04.4 with minimum install to a device that has RAID 1 configured in BIOS. During installation I selected to **erase disk** and **use LVM with new Ubuntu installation** and checked the box for **Encrypt the installation for security**.

The installation shows completed but after the reboot it shows

```
cryptsetup: Waiting for encrypted source device /dev/mapper/isw_eecibhicj_Volume1p3...
```

and then dropped to a shell terminal.

Has anyone seen this issue before or have any pointers?